# Issue with main_print function

Tags: python-3.6, decorator

I am trying out a simple python program with decorator function.  It is strange that the program only execute the print statement from the decorator function, but not the calling function main_print?

```
decor.py

def decorator(some_func):
  def wrapper():
        print('execute wrapper function from the decorator function')
  return wrapper

@decorator
def main_print():
  print('executing main_print')

main_print()
```

Output shows:

```
$ python3 decor.py 
print('execute wrapper function from the decorator function')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to call the function inside the decorator eg

```
decor.py

def decorator(some_func):
  def wrapper():
        print('execute wrapper function from the decorator function')
        some_func()    # call the passed function        
  return wrapper

@decorator
def main_print():
  print('executing main_print')

main_print()
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah your'e right.  I realized that a little after I posted, but only saw your answer now while checking my past posts. Thank you.